# Cygwin cron starts at wrong time

Tags: cygwin, cron

I have a cron job starting at 1 o'clock everyday

```
0 1 * * * somescript
```

the script downloads updates my files, however when I check my modified date the earliest file says it was modified at 3:30 A.M. and this happened for 2 days now, so I tried

```
*/1 * * * * date >> c:/date.txt
```

and saw that the date is fine. Is there something else throwing cron's timing off by 2 and a half hours? or does cron use some other timing that I need to correct?

If all else fails I guess I could just move my script timing up to 30 10 * * * but I'd like to get the time corrected/find out what I'm doing wrong.

My curl output:

Fri Jul 02 3:31:43 AM Central Daylight Time 2010

myfile

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

100  273k  100  273k    0     0   427k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  460k

So it didn't take that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron entry seems correct. Did the file take a long time to download so the modification date was later? Or aanother process could have modified the files later on?

Comment: It's a ~274 KB text file so I don't think that's the problem. I output my curl log with a time stamp at the top, here's what I have. It seems to be working correctly and didn't take a long time to download, I'll edit my question.

Comment: OK. That would seem to suggest something else modified it later on. Is it always modified at 3.30AM on the current day?

Comment: I've only ran it two days, and yes, both days it has modified time ~3:30 AM. The script calls curl to download the file, but it seems from the download log curl only starts downloading at ~3:30AM so I suspect nothing is modifying it later and that's when my download script starts running.

Comment: Yes, it seems that someone was using all the computers for a couple weeks to test some apps that messed with the time and just didn't tell anyone because he switched it back before we arrived...